# Вывод имени пользователя из информации SQL

Tags: php, sql, веб-программирование

Необходимо вывести информацию о текущем пользователе в виде "*Привет %username%*".
Как я понимаю в моём случае это можно сделать либо через куки, либо через хэш который записывается в БД при авторизации.
Как можно вытащить эту информацию?
Заранее спасибо!

**Таблица в PMA:**
[image: Таблица]

**Код формы авторизации:**

```
// Соединямся с БД
include "settings.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // Вытаскиваем из БД запись, у которой логин равняеться введенному
    $query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT user_id, user_password FROM users WHERE user_login='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['login'])."' LIMIT 1");
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    // Сравниваем пароли
    if($data['user_password'] === md5(md5($_POST['password'])))
    {
        // Генерируем случайное число и шифруем его
        $hash = md5(generateCode(10));

        // Записываем в БД новый хеш авторизации и IP
        mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE users SET user_hash='".$hash."' ".$insip." WHERE user_id='".$data['user_id']."'");

        // Ставим куки
        setcookie("id", $data['user_id'], time()+60*60*24*30);
        setcookie("hash", $hash, time()+60*60*24*30,null,null,null,true);

        // Переадресовываем на страницу админки
        if ($_POST['login'] === 'admin') {
            header("Location: admin.php"); exit();
        }
        else {
            header("Location: ../index.php"); exit();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h2>Вы ввели неправильный логин / пароль</h2>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну дык получите пользователя по его id и выводите потом что нужно

Comment: Зачем вам в куки записывать id и hash? Сессию уже не модно использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь очень простое решение. Почитайте про переменные сессий в php - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.session.php , так вот, краткое решение - берете юзернейм юзера из бд и записываете его в $_SESSION['Username']. => дальше, например при редиректе на страницу с приветствием вызываете $_SESSION['Username'].